# ASPX Cookies lost

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have an issue with ASP.NET cookies being lost between requests.

I have an ASCX control which has multiple filtering checkboxes. I can check/uncheck these checkboxes and then I click a . In this applyFilters method, I am setting cookies based on whether the checkboxes are checked/unchecked. The code that does this is :

```
public void setFilterCookie(string name, string val)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) && (val != null && !val.Equals("-1")))
        {
            if (request.Cookies[name] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(name);
                myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2d);
                response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
                request.Cookies.Remove(name);
            }

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(name, val);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);           
            response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        else
        {

            if (request.Cookies[name] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(name);
                myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2d);
                response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
                request.Cookies.Remove(name);

            }
        }
    }
```

After the cookies are set, I want to databind a grid from the parent container of the control. In this databind method I am reading the cookies using the following method :

```
public string getCookie(string cookieName)
    {
        if (isNotNullOrEmpty(cookieName))
            return request.Cookies[cookieName].Value.ToString().Trim();
        else
            return null;
    }
```

The problem is that when I am setting the cookies, I can see the values being set (e.g. response.Cookies["Domain"] = "5") but when I am reading them the value is string empty.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be removing request cookies and adding response cookies with the same name multiple times. This should work.

```
    public void setFilterCookie(string name, string val)
    {
        var cookieValue = string.Empty;
        var expires = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val) && !val.Equals("-1"))
        {
            cookieValue = val;
            expires = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            expires = -2;
        }

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(name, cookieValue) {Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(expires)};
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I am still losing the cookie values